# Spring Data - JPA, customizing Repository not working

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I want to add a method to all JPA repositories and I followed the [manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) and created the following classes:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
interface BillingEntityJPARepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

     /**
      * @return
      */
      public Set<T> findAllWithoutNullableObject(Class<T> clazz);
}

public class BillingEntityJPARepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements BillingEntityJPARepository<T, ID> {

    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private NullObjectsCache nullObjectsCache;

  /**
   * @param domainClass
   * @param em
   */
   public BillingEntityJPARepositoryImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
   super(domainClass, em);
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
    @Override
    public Set<T> findAllWithoutNullableObject(Class<T> clazz) {
    //...
    }

}

public class BillingEntityJPARepositoryFactoryBean<R extends JpaRepository<T, I>, T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I> {

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
    return new BillingEntityJPARepositoryFactory(entityManager);
}

private static class BillingEntityJPARepositoryFactory<T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

private EntityManager entityManager;

/**
 * @param entityManager
 */
public BillingEntityJPARepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
    super(entityManager);
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
protected Object getTargetRepository(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
    return new BillingEntityJPARepositoryImpl<T, I>((Class<T>) metadata.getDomainClass(), entityManager);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
    return BillingEntityJPARepository.class;
    }
    }
}
```

Also I modified repository configuration:

```
<repositories base-package="xx.yy.billing.domain.repository.jpa" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" factory-class="xx.yy.billing.domain.repository.jpa.BillingEntityJPARepositoryFactoryBean"/>
```

And finally I made all my repository interfaces extend BillingEntityJPARepository, now whenever I use any repository everything works fine unless I call the method defined in BillingEntityJPARepository (findAllWithoutNullableObject) it gives me the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor can not access a member of class com.colureware.billing.domain.repository.jpa.BillingEntityJPARepository with modifiers "public abstract"
at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:95)
at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(AccessibleObject.java:261)
at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:253)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:594)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:368)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:349)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
... 61 more
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a stupid mistake I forgot the public modifier in BillingEntityJPARepository declaration.